# nuget.exe in web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

I have added few packages from NUGETin visual studio 2012. I see nuget.exe in the project. I have not come across this before as I have not yet seen nuget.exe in my other web applications. I searched in GOOGLE about this but have not found good answer. Why is nuget.exe added? Is there any reason I might need it? Any help would be apperciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have installed "NuGet.CommandLine" package or some other packages related to it.

Using "nuget.exe", you can installing NuGet packages directly from the command line.
The good things about "nuget.exe" , is if you just want NuGet to download the assemblies for you, 
it'll leave the rest to you. It saves you time by letting you easily download the pieces 
and their dependencies, it doesn’t force you into a development model you don't want.

If you don't need it, you also can use NuGet to uninstall it.